# Вывод LayOut на другое activity

Tags: java, android

Есть разные layout'ы на разных activity, к каждому присвоены свои id'и. Вопрос: можно ли выводить эти layout'ы  на другом activity со всеми содержащимися данными внутри этих ЛэйАутов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, зачастую и нужно, если есть возможность повторно использовать файл разметки, почему бы нет.

Comment: А можно по подробней, как это осуществить?

Comment: Разметку устанавливает вызов метода [`Activity.setContentView(int layoutResID)`][1], параметром ему передаётся id желаемого layout (обычно это делается в `onCreate()`, но, при необходимости можно сменить UI в любой момент). 


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)